# Hotwire/Rails: Cleanest way to handle updating content under a modal that can be opened from multiple places?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

Somewhat new to hotwire. Come from a rails api/react background so perhaps that's messing me up.

I have a modal that can be opened from many places within my app. We can call it `_foo_modal.html.erb`.  In the modal, a user can update data that should change what the content under the modal looks like. However, what that content is varies greatly depending on the context the modal was opened within.

Right now, the actions (many) that one can take within modal all go to the same controller. And within that controller, I'm trying to render the correct turbostream to update the underlying content.

That code looks somewhat like this:

```
class FooController

  def create
    # create foo
    if params[:modal_context] == 'Bar'
      render bar.turbo_stream.erb
    elsif params[:modal_context] == 'Baz'
      render baz.turbo_stream.erb
    # etc etc.
 
  end
end
```

And I have to do this for every action one can take within the modal-- essentially any action that one can take within a controller that the modal can hit has to know about every possible view context that it can be called from. This feels like it has to be a terrible anti-pattern. So what is a better alternative?

In React, we'd just return the data-- stick it in the right context high enough in the tree and let the data determine what gets rendered. But that's not the hotwire way.

Comment: Hiya, can you explain/show what you are expecting to happen in  bar.turbo_stream.erb && baz.turbo_stream.erb. Are they rendering multiple partials to different parts of the page?